# Setting fixed height panes based on responsive layouts

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, performance

I have a webapp that follows responsive design and has following layout structure. The left layout appears when window's `width > 768px` and right layout shows otherwise.

[image: Layout difference based on window's width]

Based on preliminary research I think there are no modern pure CSS ways of doing it so I implemented a jQuery code to solve it.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if (window.innerWidth > 768) {
        fixedHeight = window.innerHeight - $('.search__results').position().top;
        $('.search__results').addClass('overflow-y-scroll').height(fixedHeight);
    } else {
        $('.search__results').removeClass('overflow-y-scroll').height('auto');
    }
});
```

And my CSS class is shown

```
.overflow-y-scroll {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

I would like to leave my code up here for review and seek for DRY-er code, some spots I think may be up for improvement.

> 768px being fixed, should it be called from a global variable where it is the single point for setting the breakpoints? if yes I wonder where it should be placed so SCSS and javscripts can both use it?

-

> should I name $('.search__results') as a variable? or perhaps even make it a more generic helper function? if yes? any tips on how to write it?

I am also curious what is usually the best practice when creating such responsive layouts.

thanks!

==========

**Edit 1**: (Observation) It doesn't call before user initiate a resize action.

**Edit 2**: (Improvement) Delay can be initiated to prevent calling resize action px by px

Comment: You know the @media css tags? w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp (yes, double answered as you doubleposted. ;))

Comment: Yes @Jordumus. However the height has to be fixed and have a value that changes every time the window gets resized. So I think media query cannot do the job?

Comment: for the height: indeed, but you can change the overflow-y-scroll class that way, that it only triggers when the screen is smaller than X pixels in css, that way you don't have to add/remove it all the time. :)

Comment: Essentially I am trying to achieve similar layout as shown in this site: https://www.getaround.com/search

Comment: @Jordumus Yes indeed, you are right :)

Comment: Other than that the code looks quite clean tbh. You could cache that element in a variable if you want, especially if you foresee a lot of resizing, but it's not like you call it 100 times in 1 function so that should be ok.

Comment: @ChrisYeung have you tried my css proposal?

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan I don't think it is what i was looking for. Displaying height in % is not ideal for my situation as the filter has to be fixed height.

Comment: Please write all the requirements in the question so I can update my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can create a media query in your css, so you don't have to add and remove `overflow-y-scroll` all the time.

```
.overflow-y-scroll-small {
      height: auto;
  }

@media screen and (max-width: 768px)
  .overflow-y-scroll-small {
      overflow-y: scroll;
  }
```

So if the screen is larger than 768px, the scroll will be `auto`, if not it will be `scroll`.

You could also cache the element in a global variable if you want: (why the double underscore btw?)

```
var searchResults = $(".search__results");
$(window).resize(function() {
    if (window.innerWidth > 768) {
        fixedHeight = window.innerHeight - $('.search__results').position().top;
        searchResults.height(fixedHeight);
    } else {
        searchResults.height(''); //empty it so the css takes over.
    }
});
```

If you really want to focus on optimalisation, you could also keep a boolean to see if it's larger or not, like this:

```
var searchResults = $(".search__results");
var smaller = false;
$(window).resize(function() {
    if (window.innerWidth > 768) {
        fixedHeight = window.innerHeight - $('.search__results').position().top;
        searchResults.height(fixedHeight);
        smaller = true;
    } else if (smaller){
        searchResults.height(''); //empty it so the css takes over.
        smaller = false;
    }
});
```

This way, the height won't reset every time.